# Logback Custom JSON appender

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I need to add a prefix to the console logs. I have configured the logback with a console appender with a custom json layout.

How can I add a prefix to the json struture similar to this > **[time][tag]**{"env":"dev","url":"someurl"............}

Here is the logback configuration:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
     
        <layout class="com.logging.CustomJsonLayout">
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: You can't because it's JSON

Answer (score 0):

You approach is wrong.
Instead of creating a custom JSON layout class,
just always send JSON to the logger and
define an encoder pattern to match your desired format.

The pattern will be something like this:
`%date TAG %msg%n`